# CXF web services and Spring

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf

I am new to the CXF world but have beed programming WCF web service for years.  I have bought a book on CXF and there seems to be an implicit assumption that CXF and Spring work together.  Whereas I can see that this is fine on the server I cant believe that this is correct for a client.  Eventually I want to hook CXF services up to say Oracle OSB or maybe a Biztalk orchestration I am struggling to see how this would work with the assumption that each client must create a client-beans.xml file.  I am hoping that the replies will state that I am operating under the wrong assumption and that you can have a spring ware server implementation without the client having any knowledge of Spring but rather rely just on the service contract available at the endpoint.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It used to be true.   Prior to CXF 2.4, CXF used Spring internally to wire itself together.  Thus, Spring was required.  Recent versions of CXF now use different mechanisms and thus don't require the use of Spring for most use cases.  (some things like the JMS transport do still require it)